# Text not visible in AlertDialog for iOS7 using Titanium 3.1.3.GA

Tags: titanium, ios7

Certain long strings are not visible on iOS7 when rendered in an alert dialog,
ie.

```
Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({message: offending_string...
```

Refer:
https://gist.github.com/cornflakesuperstar/6680066

Comment: This has now been posted as an appcelerator bug: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-8003

Answer (score 0):

The property to set is not `text` but [`message`](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.AlertDialog-property-message).

Like this:

```
var dialog = Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({
    message: 'Here is my message on the dialog',
    title: 'Here is my title'
}).show();
```

Comment: oops, created the stackoverflow post with 'text' instead of 'message'. I have edited that now, thanks Josiah. As per the gist, this is still not working.